# Is there is any libraries or SDK for WorldPay integration in iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, worldpay

I am developing an iPhone application, in which, to complete the registration process, there is a need for the user to pay some amount via Paypal and WorldPay. But, I have got the (MECL) library for Paypal integration in iPhone and it is working fine. And also,i have searched but i can't find, any library for WorldPay. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

No. they don't provide any library.

Another solution is to use a UIWebView to hit the url to their website to make the payment.

But I don't know if Apple will allow that to be on the AppStore.

Comment: This might help answer my earlier statement. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15815712/uiwebview-payment-processing