# UIWebView Payment Processing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, payment-processing, worldpay

I am implementing a purchasing system for physical items in an app, because it's not digital goods it won't be classed as in-app-purchase.

The payment service I need to use don't have a public API. So I was wondering if I can hit their url in a UIWebView and make the payment through there.

Will it get accepted in the AppStore?

Or will I have to leave my app and go to Safari to finish the transaction?

thanks

Comment: The problem with not using an API and using URLs is that it might change over time. Is the payment service aware that you will be relying on their URLs not changing? I don't think Apple will have an issue, but if you're just hitting a URL and not displaying the content, just use NSUrlRequest.

Comment: Yes, the payment service is aware. I was just worried what will happen from Apple's side.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is fine, no need to switch out to safari. Just make sure the url has the `https` prefix so that the creditcard is processed over ssl.